# Can root partitions be reused?

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I chose the something-else method of installing it where it let me manually set the partitions. I already had 18.04 LTS on my computer, and I was doing this to reinstall it (since I kept getting a kernel-panic error). I set the root partition to the old root partition of Ubuntu, and I set the home partition to a home partition I'm sharing with another distro.

Ubuntu installed itself, but now when it boots to the login screen, one of two things happens. If I login with Ubuntu on Wayland, then I get a black screen with a blinking underscore at the top left. If I use Ubuntu (Default) or GNOME, then it takes me back to the login screen.

I've tried some methods like deleting the 
~/.Xauthority and ~/.ICEauthority files, reinstalling lightdm, and removing Nvidia drivers (and I didn't even have any to begin with), but none of those have worked which has led me to think that there was a problem with the way I partitioned.

Also, the home partition is low on storage (less than 8 GB free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Yes, root partitions can be reused**. All partitions and drives can be reused until they wear out or are damaged physically in some other way.
- It is a good idea to format the root partition before reusing it. Otherwise some junk from the previous system may interfere with the new system.
- It is possible to reuse the content of the home partition. Most of the time it works well, if you upgrade the same distro and flavour, but sometimes there are problems.
- I would *not* share the home partition with another distro. I would not even share it with another flavour of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu). That is asking for conflicts because of some files that should be different for the two distros/flavours.
- Instead of sharing the home partition, you can have a separate **data** partition. This partition can have an `ext4` file system, if all operating systems are linux. Otherwise, if dual booting with Windows, the partition should have the NTFS file system.

Comment: It worked! Looking at what you said, I formatted the existing root and used a different home directory. Have a blessed day!

Comment: @christophrrb, I'm glad I could help :-)